# How to Live-Edit JavaScript in LightTable?

Tags: javascript, lighttable

How to Live-Edit JavaScript in LightTable? I'm currently injecting my JS in the LT browser by 'eval' (ctrl+shift+enter) every time.  I'm looking for the JS equivalent of the HTML_live plugin.  https://github.com/existentialmutt/lighttable-html-live

Answer (score 1):

Hey I think what you are looking for is something similar to this:

```
[:editor.javascript :lt.objs.editor/on-change :eval-editor]
```

I hope it helps